# ArgumentException: Cannot bind to the target method because its signature is not compatible with that of the delegate type

Tags: c#, reflection

```cs
private const string ReferencedAssemblyName = "System.Private.CoreLib";

private delegate IntPtr DllImportResolver(string libraryName, Assembly assembly, DllImportSearchPath? searchPath);
private delegate void SetDllImportResolverDelegate(Assembly assembly, DllImportResolver resolver);

private static readonly SetDllImportResolverDelegate _setDllImportResolverCallback;

static Program()
{
    Assembly coreLibAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
        .GetAssemblies()
        .FirstOrDefault((assembly) => assembly.GetName().Name == ReferencedAssemblyName);

    if (coreLibAssembly != null)
    {
        MethodInfo[] methods = coreLibAssembly
            .GetTypes()
            .FirstOrDefault((type) => type.Name == "NativeLibrary")
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

        foreach (MethodInfo method in methods)
        {
            if (method.Name == "SetDllImportResolver")
                _setDllImportResolverCallback = (SetDllImportResolverDelegate)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(SetDllImportResolverDelegate));
        }
    }
}

static void Main()
{
    _setDllImportResolverCallback(typeof(NativeLibrary).Assembly, (libraryName, assembly, searchPath) =>
    {
        return NativeLibrary.Load("Kernel32");
    });
}
```

Im getting this exception when im trying to create delegate for "SetDllImportResolver" method. My delegate has same structure like in System.Private.CoreLib. How can i make it works?

Comment: Your `DllImportResolver` is not the same type as the one the real method uses.  The runtime gives you no points for having "the same structure", .NET isn't duck-typed.  You will have to use reflection to get the real type and create an instance of it from your lambda.

Comment: I'm quite curious at what it even is you're attempting to do here. Relying on a class living in `System.Private.CoreLib` is a very specific implementation detail indeed. What's wrong with calling `NativeLibrary.SetDllImportResolver` directly?

Comment: .NET Standard don't have `NativeLibrary` class

Comment: Then what you probably *should* do is not pretend your library is .NET Standard, unless this DLL resolver logic is optional and everything works fine without it. Consider building the library for both .NET Core and .NET Framework (in either case, the lowest versions you're willing to support). You could leave a Standard version as a fallback for things like Mono, but then you probably want to exclude this logic.

Comment: As i know .NET Core uses Mono developments. Does it means that .NET Core has dllmap support? Or it was removed for the `NativeLibrary` implementation?

Comment: .NET Core is not Mono. It has developers who worked on Mono working on it and it took a lot of inspiration from Mono, sure, but they are definitely different frameworks. .NET Core does not directly support Mono's DllMap, but such support [can be implemented](https://learn.microsoft.com/samples/dotnet/samples/dllmap-demo/) using `NativeLibrary`.